# How to apply a background_gradient to the first n greatest values in a pandas dataframe's column?

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, max, gradient

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 222 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 11 | 21414 |
| 12 | 33 |
| 113 | 123 |

I discovered recently pandas dataframes formatting and encountered the following problem:
I would like the above table to look like the following picture, **if n = 3**:

[image: Formatted table]

I didn't find an application of the style.background_gradient*()* method for this use case. I tried the highlight_max(), but it only formats 1 cell per column.

Thank you!

Comment: I think your question initially got misunderstood, you want to color only the top N values in each column?

Answer (score 4):

##### manually highlighting the top 3

```
mapper = {1: '#0313FF', 2: '#0063FA', 3: '#3E89FB'}

def top3(df):
    return (df.rank(ascending=False)
              .apply(lambda s: 'background-color: '+s.map(mapper))
           )

df.style.apply(top3, axis=None)
```

Output:

[image: style top 3 color]

##### in combination with [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) and [`background_gradient`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.background_gradient.html) using the `gmap` parameter:

```
N = 3

df.style.background_gradient(axis=None, cmap=cm,
                             gmap=df.rank(ascending=False).rsub(N+1).clip(lower=0)
                            )
```

Output:

[image]

---

##### older answer: details on using `background_gradient`

This is well described in the [style user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1/user_guide/style.html#Builtin-styles).

Use [`style.background_gradient`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.background_gradient.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

cm = sns.light_palette('blue', as_cmap=True)

df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
```

Output:

[image: pandas style gradient color]

As you see, the output is a bit different from your expectation:

[image: expected output]

You can however use a non-linear scale, for example by passing the log values using `gmap`, and uncompressing the low values (`low` parameter).

```
import numpy as np

df_log = np.log(df)

df.style.background_gradient(gmap=df_log.div(df_log.max()),
                             low=-0.3, cmap=cm, axis=None)
```

Output:

[image: non-linear scale pandas style color gradient]

Comment: The combination of rank and background_gradient is really good for my use case (should've explained my problem more broadly), as it allows also to highlight the N lowest values. I wanted to highlight the highest values in a specific subset of columns, and the lowest values in another specific subset of columns. This answer is excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Styler object as indicated in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

Try the following:

```
from IPython.display import display #I assume you are in a notebook

_min = df.values.min() #white value
_max = df.values.max() #darkest blue value

df = df.style.background_gradient(axis=None, vmin=_min, vmax=_max, cmap="Blues")
display(df)
```

If you want to have a different scale per each column, simply omit setting `vmin` and `vmax` values.

```
df.style.background_gradient(cmap="Blues")
```

Here is a list of [available color maps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)

Comment: If you set a `vmin`/`vmax` this will use the same scale for all values, it rather looks like OP wants a scale per column

Comment: @mozway you are right, I didn't notice it.

Comment: (to be fair what is really expected is unclear, the scale in the example doesn't look linear)

Comment: True, but 113 and 21414 have the same color. So, for sure there are no global vmin/vmax. Anyway, I have added the other option.

Comment: I think I got it, I believe OP wants to color gradient the top N values